# Hamiltonian flow generated by angular momentum

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, flow

Hamiltonian flow generated by angular momentum function $
J(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{p})=x_{1} p_{2}-x_{2} p_{1}
$ is given by:
$$
\begin{array}{r}
{\left[\begin{array}{l}
x_{1}(t) \\
x_{2}(t)
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\cos t & -\sin t \\
\sin t & \cos t
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}
x_{1}(0) \\
x_{2}(0)
\end{array}\right]} \\
{\left[\begin{array}{c}
p_{1}(t) \\
p_{2}(t)
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\cos t & -\sin t \\
\sin t & \cos t
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
p_{1}(0) \\
p_{2}(0)
\end{array}\right]}
\end{array}
$$

The problem is :

> why the solution does not have the interpretation of time evolution of particle
> i.e. $t$ should not be interpreted as the physical time.It's just the
> parameter in a one-parameter group of diffeomorphisms.

[This is the statement in Brain C.Hall's QM book page 39]

Comment: The quoted  statement does not seem problematic-- except that it is an incomplete sentence.  What *is* the problem?

Comment: @mike stone the problem is why $t$ in the solution should not be interpreted as physical time. It seems quite natural to view the solution as  time evolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* regard it as time were  $J=xp_y-yp_x$ an actual hamiltonian. For example a spin in a magnetic field has $H= -\mu {\bf J}\cdot {\bf B}$ and this leads to Larmor precession in which the spin just rotates about the direction of ${\bf B}$ . The author is simply making the point that continuous symmetry operations (here a rotation) are also hamiltonian flows, but ones where the  parameter (here the angle of the rotation) plays the role of  "time".